# change navigation bar button item color in ios6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, ios6

I want to change navigation bar back button color for iOS6, I try my best but can't got success. So please can any one help me to find out perfect solution?

I want to make this button background black.

I had used

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

but it doesn't work. I had also used this one too:

```
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

but got this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationBar setBarTintColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9d2ab30
```

Comment: Still supporting iOS 6 ? It must be a pain considering [Apple's latest numbers](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/) indicate 90% of users are on iOS 7, and iOS 6 market share will most probably be even lower once iOS 8 comes out...

Comment: yup i know but my client want app in ios6 and ios7 both.

Comment: Ohh thank You If you have solution for this then please tell me...

Comment: U want to change only back button colour or entire navigationbar?

Answer (score 1):

in `iOS 6`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

in ios7

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

another choice

```
//allocating the bar button
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(popToBack)];

 //assign the bar button to the navigation bar

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;

//change the tint color of the bar button item
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:125.0/255.0 green:90.0/255.0 blue:146.0/255.0 alpha:1];  //[UIColor blackColor]


-(void)popToBack
{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: you need to change the bar button background color

Comment: @user3824002 I updated my answer try this,i am waiting for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Try this

// UIBarItem appearance

```
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 [UIColor colorWithRed:140.0f/255  green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor,
 [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
 [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
 [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica neue" size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont,
 nil]
 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

// using image

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:doneBackgroundImage
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: not working any other solution? thanks for giving replay

Comment: You ca try also with custom image, but this code should work! I am adding that into my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  CGRect rectQuestion=CGRectMake(0 , 0, 50, 30);
    UIButton *btnLeft=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    [btnLeft setFrame:rectQuestion];
    [btnLeft setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
    [btnLeft setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [btnLeft removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
    [btnLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(PopThis) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *leftBar=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btnLeft];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=leftBar;
    [btnLeft release];
    [leftBar release];
```